# reading int from file store first line in variables in c

Tags: c

I am trying to read ints from a txt file and store the first line into three variable and the rest into an array.

```
 while(fgets(lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), inputFile) != NULL){

   fscanf(inputFile, "%d %d %d", &pages, &frames, &requests);
   printf("\n\nin loop to get first line variables:\n Pages: %d\n frames: %d\n requests: %d", pages, frames, requests);
 }
```

Input file: the numbers with the first row being the first three and every row afterwards just being a single number.

```
8 12 4 
4
3
4
...
```

when i run the program, it skips the 12 and 4.

Comment: Why the `fscanf`? Shouldn't you be using `sscanf(lineBuf . . .` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It skips because you are reading the file with `fgets` as well, so `fgets` get
the first line, `fscanf` the second line but leaves the newline in the input
buffer, so `fgets` will read only an empty line, etc. It's a bad idea to mix
both reading function.

The best thing would be to read all lines with `fgets` and parse each line with
`sscanf`. Use the return value of `sscanf` to determine how many integer you've
read. From your input it seems that a line can have 1, 2 or 3 integers. So this
would do:

```
char line[1024];
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, inputFile))
{
    int pages, frames, requests, ret;

    ret = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &pages, &frames, &requests);

    if(ret < 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing the line, no numbers\n");
        continue;
    }

    if(ret == 1)
    {
        // do something with pages
    } else if(ret == 2) {
        // do something with pages & frames
    } else if(ret == 3) {
        // do something with pages, frames and requests
    }
}
```

---

*edit*

based on your comments, of only the first line has 3 values and the rest of the
lines have one value each, then you can simplify the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parse_file(const char *fname, int *pages, int *frames, int *request, int *vals, size_t size)
{
    size_t idx = 0;

    if(fname == NULL || pages == NULL || frames == NULL
            || request == NULL || vals == NULL)
        return -1;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", fname);
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", pages, frames, request) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong format, expecting pages, frames and requests\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    // reading all other values and storing them in an array
    while((idx < size) && (fscanf(fp, "%d", vals + idx) == 1)); // <-- note the semicolon

    fclose(fp);
    return idx; // returning the number of values of the array
}

int main(void)
{
    int pages, frames, request, vals[100];

    int num = parse_file("/your/file.txt", &pages, &frames, &request,
                vals, sizeof vals / sizeof vals[0]);

    if(num == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot parse file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // your code

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlekMIller bear in mind that `fgets` after `fscanf` will pick up an empty line, due to the newline left in the buffer. Don't mix input methods with different behaviour.

Comment: for the input just the first line is three integers and the rest are one value. thank you.

Comment: @AlekMIller Why are you reading 3 numbers in a loop if that's only the first line?

Comment: the first line is pages frames requests. then after that i have to store the rest in an array.

Comment: @AlekMIller I've made an update of the answer based on your comments.

Comment: thank you all for the help. i was getting confused with fgets and scan function.